# Can I see only unclassified items on Zetero web?

Tags: untagged

Zotero main webpage shows all my items where some are classified in the subfolders and some are not.

I would like to see only unclassified items in the main page.

Is it possible in the Zotero web version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, not possible. That would be the "Unfiled" collection in the Zotero desktop application, but neither that nor any substitute exists in the web library.

---

###### Sources

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/zotero/web-library) has two related issues:

- [Support for "Unfiled Items" and "Duplicate Items"](https://github.com/zotero/web-library/issues/146)
  issue #146 / updated 2020-10-16 / opened 2018-10-17
- [Special collections](https://github.com/zotero/web-library/issues/72)
  issue #72 / closed 2018-10-17 / opened 2017-02-27

On June 11, 2020 [Zotero](https://github.com/zotero) member Tom Najdek ([@tnajdek](https://github.com/tnajdek)) posted [the following comment](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/comment/358187/#Comment_358187) on their discussion forum:

> ...*It's not currently possible to view unfiled items or duplicates in the web library. Adding these is [planned](https://github.com/zotero/web-library/issues/146) but we don't have a firm date at this point...*

Comment: @Asahiko great links.  Also, remember that you can [edit] a post to improve it.  See "[When should I edit posts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/editing#:~:text=To%20include%20additional%20information%20only%20found%20in%20comments%2C%20so%20that%20all%20of%20the%20information%20relevant%20to%20the%20post%20is%20contained%20in%20one%20place)"  Excerpt: *"to include additional [relevant] information only found in comments"*